# C# Resources vs XAML Resources

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, xaml, resources

I am a beginner and I am a bit confused with the .net terminology.
I can create a Resource for app localization and for pictures, icons ...
I can also create a resource for a ControlTemplate or DataTemplate,...

Is it the same name for two different things? Or is there a relation between resources defined in XAML and resources defined by adding in the Visual Studio?

Thank you very much for your anwers.
Regards,
Radek

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same thing.  Traditional .NET resources (images, strings, ...) are sometimes referred to in the WPF world as *binary* resources, and resources used by WPF, typically defined in XAML are referred to as *logical* resources.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same. 
Maybe you should consider taking a closer look at what you *produce*. I think you should download [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) and make a habit of looking over the output artifacts. Even though the terminology on a code level are similar, you will see that they are completely different things in the output assemblies.